# PHP fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a PHP script that connects to an api and posts information to their systems, but when its trying to connect it throws a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Problem with
'http://apitestserver.co.uk:9000/Service.svc/Items' in
/var/www/html/e/connect_test.php:17 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/html/e/connect_test.php(39): 
do_http_request('http://apitest....', 'hello') #1 {main} thrown in 
/var/www/html/e/connect_test.php on line 17
```

If I send it to a PHP script which just grabs the IP then it works, but if I send it to the API it doesn't.  My PHP script creates XML and then forwards to the server.  I was getting errors so I just created the following smaller script purely to test the connection:

```
function do_http_request($url, $data, $method = 'POST', 
    $optional_headers = 'Content-Type: application/atom+xml') {

  $params = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => $method,
        'content' => $data
    )
  );

  if ($optional_headers !== null) {
    $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
  }

  $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
  $fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
  if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with $url");
  }

  $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
  if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url");
  }

  $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
  fclose($fp);

  if(!preg_match('~^HTTP.*([0-9]{3})~', 
    $metaData['wrapper_data'][0], $matches)){
    throw new Exception('MALFORED RESPONSE - COULD NOT UNDERSTAND HTTP CODE');
  }
  if (substr($matches[1], 0, 1) != '2') {
    throw new Exception('SERVER REPORTED HTTP ERROR ' . $matches[1]);
  }
  return $response;
}
$data = 'hello';
$paul = 
  do_http_request('http://apitestserver.co.uk:9000/Service.svc/Items',$data);

echo $paul;
```

If I change the URL to a simple script on another one of our servers which just grabs the IP of the incoming connection and returns it:

```
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 echo 'IP equals = ' . $ip;
```

Then it works fine with no errors.

Update -

with errors on it throws the following warning, probably because the script is not sending the correct info to the API

```
Warning: fopen(http://apitestserver.co.uk:9000/Service.svc/Items) 
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 
500 Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

Also note that I can access the api server fine using fiddler to send manually created items across, its just when this script tries to connect and send data there is an issue. I wrote another quick script which connects and prints out the default response (an rss feed of submitted items)

When I run the 'main' connector script it throws the following two errors

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in 
/var/www/html/e/sequence.php on line 65

Warning: fopen(http://apitestserver.co.uk:9000/Service.svc/Items) 
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Operation now in progress 
in /var/www/html/e/sequence.php on line 65
```

Comment: I would suggest that it has something to do with the arrays that you are using, first test if that key exists, then use it.

Comment: smoove666 yes it works fine, but its a closed server so can you delete reference to it? 
I can access it fine with a browser,I can also access it with a script and parse the response it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [curl](https://www.php.net/curl) instead of `fopen()`. curl is both more flexible, and more secure.  Many servers disable [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), curl also fails more gracefully when there are problems on the remote server.

Comment: Have not used Curl much, any pointers on which functions to use?

Comment: There's a pretty good sample that was posted in June on the example page at php.net: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the URL in my browser and got a connection error.

Maybe the problem is with their server (or you have the wrong URL)?

Edit:

Looks like ther server is throwing a 500 error - maybe because the data you're posting is invalid.

You could use a packet sniffer and check the exact data you're sending to the server (or use cURL as suggested by @acrosman)

Comment: The guy just removed the real url and put a false one so nobody would access it. "apitestserver.co.uk" should have been clear enough ;)

Comment: yeah apitestserver is a falsie as the original one is private and locked behind a firewall so no one would be able to see it anyway! But I can access it fine, from the server, as my update says.

Comment: Yes well spotted, thats because I am not sending the correct data to the API. I will update my main thread with the errors from the main script.

Answer (score 1):

apitestserver.co.uk doesn't respond to ping and the url is inaccessable. The API-server doesn't seem to be up.

Comment: Its a closed test server, you wont be able to access it without the firewall letting you through. Which it wont, but also its a closed server so could you delete reference to it please :) I thought I had replaced all instances in the original post DOH

Comment: Note I can access it fine, and i can also access it with a simple script which opens, reads and prints the xml the api returns as default.

Answer (score 0):

First error message suggests problems with apitestserver - it returns error code 500, which states for "Internal server error".

Second one informs that PHP can't resolve host name into IP address - I'd look into DNS configuration and/or hosts file.

---

Apparently 'fopen' function does not return proper stream. There can be many possibilities when that happens, but according to PHP manual, fopen function on fail should present E_WARNING message with proper commentary. It is possible that you have errors of that class silenced - call error_reporting(E_ALL) at the beginning of your script and look for some relevant error messages.

Answer (score 0):

or You can change the headers:

```
$optional_headers = 'Content-Type: application/json')
```