# Dailymotion api upload error

Tags: php, upload, dailymotion-api

I can upload video with dailymotion api with PHP but when Upload Suspended by dailymotion i can't receive error code from my upload request. My php page turn 500 internal server error. Api explorer give error result but my php script not give any result and turn 500 internal server error. How can i receive error code.

Comment: you need to detail more your request in order for anyone to help you: what's the code used, what's the answer (if any) from the api or the behavior, any logs that could help, etc

Comment: $result = $api->post(
     '/me/videos',
     array(
     'url' => $mp4,
     'title' => $baslik,
     'description' => $aciklama,
     'tags' => $etiket,
     'channel' => $channel,
     'language' => $lang,
     'private' => false,
     'published' => true)
    );   I am using this code. Whit this code. I am succescfully upload video with this. But sometimes dailymotion block upload action then this code can't return any error. Php page give me 500 internal server error

Answer (score 0):

You say you receive a `500 internal server error`. `500` is the error code, so I don't understand your request. 
If you want to know more about error codes at Dailymotion, here is the page to read: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#error-codes

Basically, you are supposed to receive an error with different information in the message body: code, messsage, type, info, etc. Please read this error to understand the root of your issue.

Regarding upload limit, Dailymotion has a policy of 4 videos maximum per hour. If you want to read the up-to-date limits, refer to this section: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#rate-limit

Some adding: regarding 500 error, it is probably sent by your server if you're not catching errors returned by Dailymotion API. I recommend you to read about it, maybe something like [PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555920/php-fatal-error-uncaught-exception-exception)